# hook_user_insert get form values?

Tags: 7, hooks, users

I defined a field `myField` through admin/configuration/manage fields. Then I implemented hook_user_insert because I want to do something with this field after the user registration. How can I access to `myField` value? I was trying with `$edit['field_myField']` but I get an array.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice for you is to install [devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module and then run this code:

```
function MY_MODULE_user_insert(&$edit, $account, $category) {
  dsm($edit);
  dsm($account);
}
```

Create new user and you will see output with structure of variables $edit and $account - this will incredibly help you to find out structure of data.

Comment: Thank you mate, yes the devel module helped me heaps!!!

Answer (score 2):

Field data is stored in arrays.

Here is a sample user account information I save from information retrieved elsewhere:

```
 $roles = user_roles();
 $userinfo = array(
      'name' => $name,
      'pass' => user_password(),
      'init' => $name,
      'status' => 1,
      'access' => REQUEST_TIME,
      'roles'        => array(array_search('student', $roles) => 1),
      'field_first_name'   => array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array( 0 => array('value' => $ldap_details['first_name']))),
      'field_last_name'    => array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array( 0 => array('value' => $ldap_details['last_name']))),
      'field_secret_number'  => array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array( 0 => array('value' => $ldap_details['secret_number']))),
      'mail' => $ldap_details['mail'],
    );
```

So as you can see field data is stored as:
`array(LANGUAGE_KEY => array(INDEX => array('value' => 'SOMETHING HERE')));`

You just access/set it as you would any PHP array.

You may get stuck if you find your fields arent in the user record -- attached fields are not eagerly loaded you have to call a function to be sure they are attached to the User entity:

```
// For speed, typically Drupal does not attach additional fields to $user
// objects, if they are not found we request attached fields now.
if (!isset($account->field_first_name ) || !isset($account->field_last_name)) {
  field_attach_load('user', array($account->uid => $account));
}
```

Comment: I don't know how can your answer help me. It's quite different. I need to implement hook_user_insert. This hook has the variable $edit, which brings the form values. My question is how can I get the value a user inputs in one of my form fields.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use something like:

```
$edit['field_myField'][$edit['language']][0]['value']
```

But you should really use dsm($edit); so you get the structure of the array correctly